# Cant get my mind around an easy Time Speed Distance question! Please help.

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, ratio

Three cyclists: A, B, C start simultaneously from P towards Q. On reaching Q, they turn back and cycle towards the starting point. On her way back, C meets B and A at a distance of 30km and 70 km respectively from Q, while B on her way back meets A at a distance of 42 km from Q.

1. What is the speed of A & C, given B's speed is 18km?
2. What is the total distance between P & Q.?

Now my approach is something like this:

Taking **B's** case,

Before B meets A,

B traveled 30+42=72 km, at a speed of 18km/hr.
In the same time, A traveled 70-42=28 km.
So Speed of A is 28/4= 7 km/hr.

However this is wrong, the speed of A is 12 km/hr.

I did it in a different way using ratios of speed and distance and got the right answer but the process was quite lengthy and needed lots of calculation.

However, my biggest question is why is my original method wrong? Where am I doing the mistake?

Comment: Can you explain why "B travelled 30+42 = 72km and A travelled 70-42 = 28 km"? It might help if you set the distance as $d$ and explain what that value is.

Comment: So C met B at a distance of 30 km from Q. After this, the next line says, B on her way back meets A at a distance of 42 km from Q. This means in the given time period, B covered the distance of 30 km(hence reaching point Q), turned back and covered additional distance of 42 km( therefore meeting A). thus total distance covered by B is 30+42=72km. B on the other hand was 70 km away, next he was 42 km away from Q. Hence he covered a distance of 70-42=28 km.

Comment: I agree that from the time B met C to B met A, B travelled 42+30 km. Where was A when B met C? Did A met C at that same time, or likely some other time?